# show several graphics in SAGE notebook

Tags: sage

I want to show several plots in the notebook, one after the other. If I have only one plot, I can usually show it with the function sum(), but if I put something else after the sum() then the plot doesn't show. So, for example, I want to show several plots one after the other by doing a while with the sum inside, but that doesn't work. It doesn't show any plot.

Comment: I decided to take down the example as it is part of ongoing research, but I have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the show() function, e.g.

```
show(sum(...))
```

Comment: In general in the notebook, only the last thing in each cell appears.  Unless, of course one `print`s or `html`s or `show`s.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you have several plots `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, which you want to display separately, is

```
graphics_array([[p1, p2], [p3, p4]])
```